# What Hebrew meaning does "Bel" or "Baal" and Baalim in Jeremiah 50:2 have or signify?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, god

Jeremiah 50:2 ASV

Declare ye among the nations and publish, and set up a standard; publish, and conceal not: say, Babylon is taken, Bel is put to shame, Merodach is dismayed; her images are put to shame, her idols are dismayed.

Comment: Baalim does not occur in Jer 50:2.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is in the situational context.

This prophecy anticipates a time when Babylon has been "taken" and destroyed. Bel, Merodach, and the other "images and idols" are the deities worshipped in Babylon. Modern historians tend to spell the second name as "Marduk". As such, these gods have a responsibility to protect Babylon and keep her safe, the equivalent of the protection which the Lord normally offers to his own people. That is what she is expecting of them. If Babylon is destroyed, then her gods have obviously let her down. They have been shown up as inadequate protectors. So they are "put to shame" and humiliated.

Answer (score 0):

Jer 50:2 says (NASB):

> “Announce and declare to the nations; lift up a banner and proclaim
> it; hold nothing back when you say, ‘Babylon is captured; **Bel** is put
> to shame; Marduk is shattered, her images are disgraced, her idols are
> broken in pieces.’

"Baalim" does no occur in this verse.

**Bel**

The word, בֵּל (Bel, Isa 46:1, Jer 50:2, 51:44) is simply a contracted form of בַּעַל (Ba'al, Jud 2:11, 13, 3:7, 6:25, 28, 1 Sam 7:4, 1 Kings 16:31, etc) which simply means, "owner" or "Lord" as in the case of Gen Ex 21:28, 29, and in some cases, "husband", as in Ex 21:3, 22, Deut 22:22, etc.

The plural form of Ba'al is Ba'alim as in Jud 8:33, 10:6, 10, etc.

**Jeremiah 50**

The prophecy in Jer 50 is simply a prophecy about the (then future) time when Babylon, its power and its false idol-god of Bel/Ba'al would be shattered, and the Israelites would return to Jerusalem.

The name מְרֹדָךְ (Merodak/Marduk) only occurs in Jer 50:2 and also signifies the chief deity of Babylon which would be shattered and broken along with the political power of babylon.